# How to transfer data to another page and make dynamic element stay?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

**How to make dynamic element stay after the page load and the data inside that dynamic element transfer to the next page?**

I need to add a new row that contain of checkbox and textbox. I'm using `Clone()` method to create a new row. But then, when I click submit, the new row gone with the new data added.

Someone told me that `clone()` method will make a temporary element and it didn't stay after the page load.  **So, should I use create() new element?** I also search the other method, and certain of them use asp:placeholder.

And my next problem, **how I want to transfer the data inside that dynamic element?** by using viewstate or session state? Because I'm not binding it into any rigid database and the form that I make, just a temporary design and the function should be work when testing being done.

For that form, I'm trying to avoid table format, and currently everything in div layout.

I've tried many method, from javascript to jquery, from `clone()` to `create()` method. But none of them give the result that I want. I'm using `VS2012`, in aspx web form. Your helps are really appreciated!

below is my code for row:

```
 <div id="rows" class="block">
            <div class="p2">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" runat="server"/>
                <input id="txt1" type="text" class="clsTxtBox10char" runat="server" maxlength="16" value="0.00" /> &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="p3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p4">
                <input id="txt2" type="text" class="clsTxtBox10char" runat="server" maxlength="16" value="0.00"/> &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="p5">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="p6">
                <input id="txt3" type="text" class="clsTxtBox10char" runat="server" maxlength="16" value="0.00"/> &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                <span style="color:red;">*</span>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="btn" class="block" style="text-align:center;">
                <asp:Button ID="addrow" runat="server" CssClass="clsButton" Text="Add Row" />
                &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="remove" runat="server" CssClass="clsButton" Text="Remove Row" width="90" />
                &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="delete" runat="server" CssClass="clsButton" Text="Delete ATL"/>
            </div>
```

below was my code for javascript:

```
var cloneCount = 1;
    //add new row
   $("#addrow").click(function () {
       $('#rows')
         .clone(true).find('input:text').attr('id', 'txts' + cloneCount++).val("").end()
         .attr('id', 'rows' + cloneCount++, 'class', 'block')
         .insertAfter('[id^=rows]:last');
       return false;
   });

   //Remove new row
   $(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
       $('#rows' + --cloneCount).remove();
       return false;
   });

   //delete atl
   $(document).on('click', '#delete', function () {
       if (!$('.checkbox').prop("checked")) {
           $find('.checkbox:checked').remove();
       }
   });
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void addrow_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel Panel1 = new Panel();

    for (int s = 0; s > 1; s++)
    {
        string input = string.Empty;

        //div that acts like row
        var row = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        row.ID = "rows" + s.ToString();
        row.Attributes.Add("class", "block");

        var c1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        c1.Attributes.Add("class", "p2");
        //add inside div row
        for (int i = 0; i > 0; i++)
        {
            input += "<input id=\"cb" + i.ToString() + "\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\"checkbox\" runat=\"server\" > </input>"
                + "&nbsp;" + "<input id=\"tb" + i.ToString() + "\" type=\"text\" class=\"clsTxtBox10char\" runat=\"server\"> </input>";
        }
        //add the string in innerHTML as
        c1.InnerHtml = input;
        row.Controls.Add(c1);

        var c2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        c2.Attributes.Add("class", "p3");
        row.Controls.Add(c2);

        var c3 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        c3.Attributes.Add("class", "p4");
        //add inside div row
        for (int i = 0; i > 0; i++)
        {
            input += "<input id=\"tbm" + i.ToString() + "\" type=\"text\" class=\"clsTxtBox10char\" runat=\"server\"> </input>";
        }
        //add the string in innerHTML as
        c3.InnerHtml = input;
        row.Controls.Add(c3);

        var c4 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        c4.Attributes.Add("class", "p5");
        row.Controls.Add(c4);

        var c5 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        c5.Attributes.Add("class", "p6");
        //add inside div row
        for (int i = 0; i > 0; i++)
        {
            input += "<input id=\"tbe" + i.ToString() + "\" type=\"text\" class=\"clsTxtBox10char\" runat=\"server\"> </input>"
                + "&nbsp;" + "<span style=\"color:red;\">*</span>";
        }
        //add the string in innerHTML as
        c5.InnerHtml = input;
        row.Controls.Add(c5);

        Panel1.Controls.Add(row);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    Response.Redirect("new_page.aspx");

    }
```

Comment: Can we see your .aspx code and code behind? From the sound of it you may have missed something there to persist the rows, such as runat="server" attribute.

Comment: @peter I've add my code.

Comment: Syafah if you dont want to save the dynamic elements even in db and no where on server side you can save it in vrowser local storage or cookie.. And when ever you page loads you can check here .. if elements present add it to your DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your dynamic rows using code behind and not jQuery.
To persist your runat="server" elements you need to have them bound to the code behind which is on the server side. I suspect this is tricky when you try to do it on the client side since there is no way the server side will know you have created a new element with jQuery.

Remove your jQuery code and allow the webpage to post back when you click on an asp:button. Then handle the click event for add, remove and delete.

To add the rows see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx